# Why does 'printf("%Lf", 1.0);' results in a segfault in C?

Tags: c

Running with mingw compiler, this line:

```
printf("%Lf", 1.0);
```

results in a segfault. Why?
I get it that '1.0' is double and not long double, as '%Lf' specifies, but I'd expect a conversion of some sort, not a segfault.

Comment: Unlike other functions in C, for `printf` the compiler does not and cannot automatically convert the type of argument you pass, to the type expected by the function being called.  I agree that a segfault is surprising, but you definitely couldn't have expected an automatic conversion.  (Also your compiler should have warned about this — did it?)

Comment: When I tried your code on my computer, it printed `-6623690567…854334607360.000000`, where the … represents about 3,800 digits that I've elided.  That is, the `long double` value that `printf` tried to print — that it constructed based on the reinterpreted bits of the `double` value that was passed, plus whatever random values it got from elsewhere — corresponded to a preposterous 3,843-digit number.  Perhaps something similar happened to `printf` on your computer, but it literally ran out of stack space for a temporary result, or something.

Answer (score 5):

There is no implicit conversion for `double` in [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) call, from [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) no mention of conversion from `double`:

> In a function call expression when the call is made to ... a variadic
> function, where the argument expression is one of the trailing
> arguments that are matched against the ellipsis parameter. Each
> argument of integer type undergoes integer promotion, and
> each argument of type float is implicitly converted to the type double

Access to individual variadic parameters is implemented via [va_arg](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg) macro. From it's documentation there is undefined behavior if expected type is different than the passed type:

> `T va_arg( va_list ap, T );`
>
> ...
>
> If the type of the next argument in ap (after promotions) is not
> compatible with T, the behavior is undefined,

`%Lf` format indicates that `printf` expects and will try to read a `long double` value, (documentation: [fprintf format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)). `long double` is mostly a 16-byte double, from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types) :

> long double - extended precision floating point type. Matches IEEE-754
> binary128 format if supported

`1.0` constant is `double` (almost always 8 bytes), from [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant):

> An unsuffixed floating constant has type double

So `long double` type is expected, but `double` is passed, which is undefined behavior. Or 16 bytes parameter is expected, but 8 bytes passed, thus a segfault on an attempt to read uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 2):

Please read up on varargs. The only information that printf has about the type of the value is the format spec. You have asked printf to fetch a big item, and supplied a small item. This could cause a misaligned fetch or, remotely, even, an access beyond the bounds of the stack.